# Track Minimum Value of a Signal In Real Time

Tags: c, signal-processing, pic

I'm currently tracking the analog value of a photodetector coming into my system. The signal itself is cleaned, filtered (low pass and high pass), and amplified in hardware before coming into my system. The signal has a small amount of DC walk to it, which is giving me some trouble. I've attempted to just move the min up by 1% every 50 reads of the ADC,but it adds more noise than I'd like to my signal. Here's a snapshot of what I'm pulling in below (blue = signal, max/min average = green, red = min) The spikes in the red signal can be ignored that's something I'm doing to say when a certain condition is met.

[image: Sample Image of Photodetector Data with Average and Min Value Shown]

Right now my function for tracking min is this:

```
        //Determine is value is outside max or min
        if(data > max) max = data;
        if(data < min) min = data;

        //Reset function to bring the bounds in every 50 cycles
        if(rstCntr>=50){ 
            rstCntr=0;
            max = max/1.01;
            min = min*1.01;
            if(min <= 1200) min = 1200; 
            if(max >= 1900) max = 1900; 
        }
```

That works fine except when I do that 1% correction to make sure we are still tracking the signal it throws other functions off which rely on the average value and the min value. My objective is to determine:

1. On the negative slope of the signal
2. Data coming in is less than the average
3. Data coming in is 5% above the minimum

It is really #3 that is driving everything else. There is enough slack in the other two that they aren't that affected.

Any suggestions for a better way to track the max and min in real-time than what I'm doing?

**EDIT:** Per comment by ryyker: here is additional information and reproducible example code

*Need more clearly described:* I'm reading an analog signal approximately once every 2ms and determining whether that signal has crossed a threshold just above the minimum value of the analog signal. The signal has some DC walk in it which doesn't allow me to simply set the lowest value seen since power-on as the minimum value.

*The question:* On a reading-by-reading basis, how can I track the min of a signal that doesn't have a consistent minimum value?

```
int main(void) {
    while (1)
    {
       
        //******************************************************************************
        //** Process analog sensor data, calculate HR, and trigger solenoids
        //** At some point this should probably be moved to a function call in System.c,
        //** but I don't want to mess with it right now since it works (Adam 11/23/2022)
        //******************************************************************************
        
        //Read Analog Data for Sensor
        data = ADC1_ReadChannel(7);  
        
        //Buffer the sensor data for peak/valley detection
        for(int buf=3;buf>0;buf--){
            dataBuffer[buf] = dataBuffer[buf-1];
        }
        dataBuffer[0] = data;
        
        //Look for a valley
        //Considered a valley is the 3 most recent data points are increasing
        //This helps avoid noise in the signal
        uint8_t count = 0;
        for(int buf=0;buf<3;buf++) {
            if(dataBuffer[buf]>dataBuffer[buf+1]) count++;
        }
        if(count >= 3) currentSlope = true; //if the last 3 points are increasing, we just passed a valley
        else currentSlope = false; //not a valley
        
        // Track the data stream max and min to calculate a signal average
        // The signal average is used to determine when we are on the bottom end of the waveform. 
        if(data > max) max = data;
        if(data < min) min = data;
        
        if(rstCntr>=50){ //Make sure we are tracking the signal by moving min and max in every 200 samples
            rstCntr=0;
            max = max/1.01;
            min = min*1.01;
            if(min <= 1200) min = 1200; //average*.5; //Probably finger was removed from sensor, move back up 
            if(max >= 1900) max = 1900; //Need to see if this really works consistently
        }
        rstCntr++;
        average = ((uint16_t)min+(uint16_t)max)/2;
        trigger = min; //Variable is only used for debug output, resetting each time around
              
        if(data < average &&
            currentSlope == false && //falling edge of signal
            data <= (((average-min)*.03)+min) && //Threshold above the min
        {            
            FireSolenoids();    
        }
    }
    return 1; 
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Here is what I'm seeing using the code posted by ryyker below. The green line is what I'm using as my threshold, which works fairly well, but you can see max and min don't track the signal.
[image]

**EDIT3:**
Update with edited min/max code. Not seeing it ever reach the max. Might be the window size is too small (set to 40 in this image).

[image]

**EDIT4:**
Just for extra clarity, I'm restating my objectives once again, hopefully to make things as clear as possible. It might be helpful to provide a bit more context around what the information is used for, so I'm doing that also.

Description:
I have an analog sensor which measures a periodic signal in the range of 0.6Hz to 2Hz. The signal's periodicity is not consistent from pulsewave to pulsewave. It varies +/- 20%. The periodic signal is used to determine the timing of when a valve is opened and closed.

Objective:

1. The valve needs to be opened a constant number of ms after the signal peak is reached, but the time it physically takes the valve to move is much longer than this constant number. In other words, opening the valve when the peak is detected means the valve opens too late.
2. Similar to 1, using the valley of the signal is also not enough time for the valve to physically open.
   [image: Late Timing from Valley and Peak]
3. The periodicity of the signal varies enough that it isn't possible to use the peak-to-peak time from the previous two pulsewaves to determine when to open the valve.
4. I need to consistently determine a point on the negative sloped portion of the pulsewave to use as the trigger for opening the valve.

Approach:

1. My approach is to measure the minimum and maximum of the signal and then set a threshold above the minimum which I can use to determine the time the open the valve.
2. My thought is that by setting some constant percentage above the minimum will get me to a consistent location on the negative sloped which can be used to open the valve.

[image: Timing from some point on the negative slope of the previous pulsewave]

Comment: Clean up what you are asking for here by removing anything that does not contribute to providing information specifically describing inputs and expected  results from the  problem.  If it discussing only the `min` signal, then get rid anything here about the other signals, they are a distraction.   Be clear on what you are doing for data sampling.  i.e. are you reading chunks of values into an array, from eg oscilloscope,  or single sample, like reading current from a power-supply.  Knowing how the data is presented will effect how the algorithm is selected to process it.

Comment: If you have working code, post it in the form of a [mcve], including a real set of example input, actual results using that data compared to expected results, and why you think your code is not working.  Need more detain on why _"...it throws other functions off..."_

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just added an EDITED section with more detail and a working set of code.

Comment: I believe you can place `data` values directly into argument 1 of the `stats()` function in example below.  The example code was tested using a test function that looped on a series scaled pseudo random numbers, where data was collected into arrays, which could then display on screen.   If it would be helpful, I could post that function into the answer below.

Comment: After having re-read your post it appears you may be actually asking values depicting confidence based on statistical contributions to error due to noise in a signal.   If so, ***std deviation*** can be used to depict _max_ and _min_ lines.  i.e.  the max line can be produced by adding value for std deviation to value of measurement, and the min line would be similar, just subtract std deviation from measurement value.  See edit to code in answer for a change that does this.

Comment: Perhaps a smoothing filter would help?

Comment: Why do you need to get three different signals from this?  Why not just convert this to a digital signal by picking a single threshold in the middle (and adding hysteresis)?  "Average" is poorly defined, what time period are you averaging over?  Do you need help designing the algorithms or just coding them in C?  Maybe you could narrow the question down and just ask about one computation at a time, I don't really want to write 3 different algorithms just hoping that all of them fit your expectations perfectly.

Comment: @ryyker you're right. That's actually what I've been doing. I thought I would need to also have a running min/max to make this work over a longer time period, but what's been working is subtracting the std_dev from the mean and then adding a threshold on top of it. That gets me the desired outcome consistently. Trick has been to get the window size correct. I widened it to 40 which works great, but more overhead than I want. Going to try and slow down the analog read rate.

Comment: @Neil believe it or not, this signal is already smoothed in hardware. It's quite noisy coming in. By adjusting the window size on the array I'm able to get some additional smoothing into it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Looks like mean and std-dev are working. The averaging time period is what I need to work on next, actually. Ideally, this average is over one period of the signal, but the frequency changes.

Comment: Is it a FM signal, or changes within measurement error?

Comment: Measurement error/drift is more accurate. It's a photocell measuring light so there's a lot of error sources.

Comment: @Adam just curious, what library / program are you using for plotting?

Comment: It's a serial data stream coming off of the microcontroller. That plot is from the Arduino Serial Plotter.

Comment: I know this is late, but can you please re-state the 3 items listed under your problem statement _"My objective is to determine:"_ .  (Eg, using objective `1.` for example.)  _"My objective is to determine on the negative slope of the signal"_.  As stated it is not clear what this means.  I am left wondering if you mean to say: _"Starting from the onset of a downward slope determine if peak data is less than the average peak value,  and by observing the onset of the following upward slope determine if data is occurring at least 5% above minimum."_.   But I am guessing.  Please re-phrase. thx.

Comment: For sure. Just added EDIT4 above. I was heads down in the lab and couldn't get an update before now.

Answer (score 1):

> *"On a reading-by-reading basis, how can I track the min of a signal that doesn't have a consistent minimum value?"*

By putting each discrete signal sample through a moving window filter, and performing statistical operations on the window as it moves,  `standard deviation` can be extracted (following mean and variance) which can then be combined with `mean` to determine the minimum allowed value for each point of a particular waveform.   This assumes noise contribution is known and consistent.

The following implementation is one way to consider.

in header file or top of .c

```
//support for stats() function
#define WND_SZ 10;
int wnd_sz = WND_SZ;

typedef struct stat_s{
    double arr[10];
    double min;     //mean - std_dev
    double max;     //mean + std_dev
    double mean;    //running 
    double variance;//running 
    double std_dev; //running 
} stat_s;

void stats(double in, stat_s *out);
```

in .c  (edit to change max and min)

```
// void stats(double in, stat_s *out)
// Used to monitor a continuous stream of sensor values.  
// Accepts series of measurement values from a sensor, 
// Each new input value is stored in array element [i%wnd_sz]
// where wnd_sz is the width of the sample array.
// instantaneous values for max and min as well as
// moving values of mean, variance, and standard deviation
// are derived once per input
void ISL_UTIL stats(double in, stat_s *out)
{
    
    double sum = 0, sum1 = 0;
    int j = 0;   
    static int i = 0;
    
    out->arr[i%wnd_sz] = in;//array index values cycle within window size

    //sum all elements of moving window array
    for(j = 0; j < wnd_sz; j++)
        sum += out->arr[j];
    //compute mean
    out->mean = sum / (double)wnd_sz;
    //sum squares of diff between each element and mean
    for (j = 0; j < wnd_sz; j++)
        sum1 += pow((out->arr[j] - out->mean), 2);
    //compute variance
    out->variance = sum1 / (double)wnd_sz;
    //compute standard deviation
    out->std_dev = sqrt(out->variance);
    //EDIT here:
    //mean +/- std_dev
    out->max = out->mean + out->std_dev;
    out->min = out->mean - out->std_dev;
    //END EDIT
    //prevent overflow for long running sessions.
    i = (i == 1000) ? 0 : ++i;
    
}
    
int main(void) 
{
    stat_s s = {0};
    bool running = true;
    double val = 0.0;

    while(running)
    {
        //read one sample from some sensor
        val = someSensor(); 
        stats(val, &s);
        // collect instantaneous and running data from s 
        // into variables here
        if(some exit condition) break
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using this code with 1000 bounded pseudo random values, `mean` is surrounded with traces depicting `mean + std_dev` and `mean - std_dev`  As `std_dev` becomes smaller over time, the traces converge toward the `mean` signal:

[image]

Note:  I used the following in my test code to produce data arrays of a  signal with constant amplitude added to injected noise that diminishes in amplitude over time.

```
void gen_data(int samples)
{
    srand(clock());
    int i = 0;
    int plotHandle[6] = {0};
    
    stat_s s = {0};
    
    double arr[5][samples];
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
    
    for(i=0; i < samples; i++)//simulate ongoing sampling of sensor 
    {
      s.arr[i%wnd_sz] = 50 + rand()%100;
      if(i<.20*samples)         s.arr[i%wnd_sz] = 50 + rand()%100; 
      else if(i<.40*samples) s.arr[i%wnd_sz] = 50 + rand()%50; 
      else if(i<.60*samples) s.arr[i%wnd_sz] = 50 + rand()%25; 
      else if(i<.80*samples) s.arr[i%wnd_sz] = 50 + rand()%12; 
      else                   s.arr[i%wnd_sz] = 50 + rand()%6; 
      
      stats(s.arr[i%wnd_sz], &s); 
      arr[0][i] = s.mean;
      arr[1][i] = s.variance;
      arr[2][i] = s.std_dev; 
      arr[3][i] = s.min;
      arr[4][i] = s.max;
    }
    //
    Plotting algorithms deleted for brevity.
}
```

Comment: This looks great. I'm going to go run it now and will report back on my findings.

Comment: @Adam - Note edit to use `out->max` rather than local `static double max;`.  Same ofr min.

Comment: I'm able to get this to work using average and std-dev, but the min and max are global, not based on the current waveform within the window. I added a screen grab in EDIT2 above.

Comment: @Adam - Did you see the edit to the code?   I decided to tighten the implementation to use the `max, min` members of the struct to ensure their values were kept for the entire session.   They worked for me.  (look for `//edited here`)

Comment: I did, yes. Thank you. I think the issue is that we don't bring min and max back in towards the mean as it is currently written. It goes to the extremes seen, but doesn't account for the signal within the window.

Comment: If you use [Welford's on-line algorithm](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/785.php) (for numerical stability), you only need to _store_ `{ size_t count; double mean, ssdm; }`.

Comment: @Adam - Have you taken another look at the edited version of my answer?   The max and min values encompass mean.  The data generation method I used to test the code is also included.

Comment: Oh geez, no I did not see your additional edits. Thanks, will try and revert back!

Comment: Thanks for that reference @Neil. Very interesting!

Comment: Max is not ever reaching the max, strangely. (See image in EDIT3 above). I wonder if the window size is too small... set to 40.

Comment: @Adam - samples/cycle and the width  of averaging window affect leading (or lagging) of values when attempting to achieve real-time, concurrent waveform bounding.   Using a specification with gaurd-banded limits , (based on previous statistical characterization of the waveform) may be what you need to consider doing here.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I had it backwards in my head.... less samples follows faster.